# Call function through pointer to class member

Tags: c++, member-pointers

In following code:

```
class foo
{
public:
    void foo_function() {};
};

class bar
{
public:
    foo foo_member;

    void bar_function(foo bar::*p_foo)
    {
        // what is the corrct sintax for following:
        this->*p_foo->foo_function(); // expression must have a pointer type??
    }
};


int main()
{
    foo foo_obj;
    bar bar_obj;
    typedef foo bar::*p_foo;
    p_foo blah = &bar::foo_member;
    bar_obj.bar_function(blah);
    return 0;
}
```

What would be correct syntax to make **bar::bar_function** work?

Comment: Precedence *and* type mismatch too: `((this->*p_foo).foo_function)();`

Comment: Can you give us more info about the syntax error you get?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant OH 2x (( )) Thanks, I tried with 1x () so I got confused tnx!

Comment: @NickL. Syntax error is commented in the code above

Comment: This is probably not a C++ question so somebody down voted me, what kind of questions are allowed then?

Comment: @codekiddy _`p_foo blah = &bar::foo_member;`_ In which way do you think that `&bar::foo_member` provides a member function pointer actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As the title of question says: "through pointer to class member" nobody talks about member function pointers.

Comment: @codekiddy Seems to be in eye of the reader :-P But definitely _`void bar_function(foo bar::*p_foo)`_ wants a member function pointer. So how can you say _we're not talking about member function pointers_??

Comment: It wants a member pointer. `foo` is a class, not a function pointer typedef.

Comment: Basically, it looks to me like OP is trying to implement multiple dispatch in a non-standard way. Maybe C++ isn't the best language for the application?

Comment: @AustinMullins I have a situation where multiple class members of same type are arguments for one handler, for each class member handler behaves differently. I could also write multiple handlers that do the same thing, but that way the code will be much shorter.

Comment: @codekiddy Sorry. Yes, it's a member pointer, not a member _function_ pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works in [ideone](http://ideone.com/WVVOC9):

```
void bar_function(foo bar::*p_foo)
{
    (this->*p_foo).foo_function();
}
```

It's all about having the right level of indirection. Since `p_foo` is a pointer to member, we need to dereference it before attempting to access it from `this`. At this point, you have the actual `foo_member` object, not a pointer to it, so you can call its `foo_function` by dot notation.